# How to fix a hanging PhoneGap .apk build?

Tags: android, phonegap

I built a "Hello World" app using PhoneGap Desktop, but now when I try to build an APK on build.phonegap.com, it just hangs. The build has been pending for 2 days now. Is there an alternative way to build the APK?

Comment: You’re not alone. My .apk builds are hanging, too. I found this, though https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2614760. Haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Thank you, It is working after delete and re-upload :)

Comment: I just tried it too and it worked for me as well. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Go to Console/Terminal
>   
>   cd Project Path
>
> ```
> cordova build android
> (or)
> cordova build ios
> ```
>
> Go to project path ->platforms -> ios/android in **finder**(`mac`)/**file explorer**(`windows`)

It converts `android`/`iOS` project and open project in `android studio`/`Xcode` and build `.apk`/`.ipa` file.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit clunky, but deleting your app from PhoneGap Build and re-adding adding the app should solve the problem. This solution was found on the [Adobe Forums](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/2614760).